# Tablespace in H2 in-mem DB

Tags: h2

Can we create a tablespace in H2?

I get errors when I create a tablespace (in H2) and then try to create tables in that tablespace.
I am creating the tablespace  and tables in Liquibase scripts and running it against an H2 database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.